# Can I connect to more than one Bluetooth HCI at the same time?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a project where I don't have enough throughput with one Bluetooth CSR USB dongle to support 3-4 heart monitors at the same time. Is there a way to connect to more than one bluetooth HCI so I can connect to more heart monitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run two instances of your bluetooth stack / driver then yes you can, But you will have to manage these 2 applications separately.
I have never seen any standard / commercial stack that handles two HCIs simultaneously.

Comment: I know of _one_ stack supporting multiple radios: BlueZ on Linux. Of course OP's platform is presumably OS X.